# PHP ignores upload_tmp_dir?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, php, iis-7

LS,

I am using IIS7 with PHP (FastCGI).

I set up the upload_tmp_dir to "X:\Temp" instead of leaving it empty, but it's still using "C:\Windows\Temp" for some reason.

I did give the following users full rights : NETWORK SERVICE, (application pool user), IIS_IUSRS. I also restarted IIS after I made the change.

I tried to create a directory inside the correct temp path using PHP, and that did work, so it's not a security issue.

Kind regards,

Matthias Vance

Answer (score 2):

Look for the setting under **Fopen wrappers** section as well.

On my installation of PHP, I found another **upload_tmp_dir** lurking in there which takes precedence because it is specified after the setting under **File uploads**

I suspect that part of the installation process for the new Windows (.msi) installations of PHP try to be a little too clever and create these settings from the system environment variables at install time instead of asking you.

In short, look for duplicate upload_tmp_dir entries in your PHP file and eliminate them.

HTH
Lewis

Comment: Good point, however, as stated before, it does show up right in phpinfo(), which means it does have the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am not understanding your question correctly.

If PHP is going to use System Environment variable for TEMP or TMP then it will point to `%SystemRoot%\TEMP`. But if there is any variable in PHP.ini which you can configure and point to a custom folder for the temporary files, then giving permissions should work. Check this out http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/upload_tmp_dir.html and  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

If PHP is still using `%SystemRoot%\TEMP`, then use Process Monitor and check at what stage the application redirect's to the `%SystemRoot%\TEMP` folder. Hopefully this should be a simple configuration issue.

Comment: There is a configuration directive 'upload_tmp_dir' which I set in PHP.ini, and is being recognized, as I can see when I execute a phpinfo() call. PHP can write to the directory just fine, it just doesn't put the uploaded files there.

I'll use a file system monitoring tool to check whether or not any security issues occur. (I do believe I have all the security settings right).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is ignoring the `upload_tmp_dir` because of one setting on APPLICATION POOLS.

It's not `php-cgi.exe`, `php.ini`, or a permissions issue.

Go to the application pool of the website experiencing the issue:

1. Right click
2. Select `Advanced settings`
3. Scroll to `LOAD USER PROFILE` and set it to `FALSE`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this can be done in Linux?